# Split comma string array ever 10th comma

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, split, group

Hey all I am trying to figure out a **better way** to split my comma separated string code into sections:

Example:
`31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,164,188,233,139,121,45,100,253,235,255,225,212,147,233,105,231,15`

This is my code I use to do the formating:

```
List<string> valueList = "31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,164,188,233,139,121,45,100,253,235,255,225,212,147,233,105,231,15".Split(',').ToList();
List<string> groupedBy10 = new List<string>();

while (valueList.Any()) {
    groupedBy10.Add(string.Join(",", valueList.Take(10)) + ",");
    valueList = valueList.Skip(10).ToList();
}

groupedBy10[groupedBy10.Count - 1] = groupedBy10[groupedBy10.Count - 1].TrimEnd(',');
string newOutput = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, groupedBy10.ToArray());
```

And this is the newOutput output:

```
31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,
164,188,233,139,121,45,100,253,235,255,
225,212,147,233,105,231,15
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Perhaps a Regex or Linq way thats shroter/faster?

Comment: Your result doesnt make sense with your input. In your second row there should be no 139 but a 146, for example.

Comment: Agree with Tim Schmelter, also the example has trailing comma, but `valueList` has not.

Comment: Good catch @TimSchmelter - I've updated my OP with the correct data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `GroupBy` with integer division:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> groupedBy10 = valueList
    .Select((s, ix) => (String:s,Index:ix))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 10)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.String));
    
IEnumerable<string> flattened = groupedBy10.Select(l => string.Join(",", l));
string newOutput = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, flattened);
```

Side-note: to remove the comma at the end of the last string, why don't you use this `String.Split` overload? No need to remove it at the end.

```
List<string> valueList = "31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,164,188,233,146,163,74,178,46,2,250,123,159,167,168,187,174,109,"
    .Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank @Tim this is a good replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just count the commas.

The idea is to enumerate the input string, character by character, counting the commas along the way. Every time you hit 10, you can then take the substring starting at the last time you hit 10 commas (or the start of the string if it's the first time) to the current character. At the end of the loop, if you haven't hit 10 commas again, then take the remainder as the final segment.

Let's put this in practice.

```
// no need to split, this can be just a string
string values = "31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,164,188,233,146,163,74,178,46,2,250,123,159,167,168,187,174,109,";
List<string> groupedBy10 = new List<string>();

// initial state
var lastIndex = 0;
var commaCount = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < values.Length; ++i)
{
    if(values[i] == ',')
        ++commaCount;

    if(commaCount == 10)
    {
        // we hit our 10th segment, get the substring
        var segment = values.Substring(lastIndex, i - lastIndex);
        groupedBy10.Add(segment);
        // reset comma count, update last index
        commaCount = 0;
        lastIndex = i + 1; // + 1 to skip the comma itself
    }       
}

if (lastIndex < values.Length)
{
    // we have some leftovers, don't forget them
    var finalSegment = values.Substring(lastIndex).TrimEnd(',');
    groupedBy10.Add(finalSegment);
}
```

Comment: Nice solution but looking to minimize my code that I currently have. This looks to add more lines to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the simplest way is to use `Chunk` from LINQ

```
var str = "31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,164,188,233,146,163,74,178,46,2,250,123,159,167,168,187,174,109,";
var valueList = str.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
var res = valueList.Chunk(10).Select(chunk => string.Join(",", chunk)).ToArray();
var newOutput = string.Join($",{Environment.NewLine}", res);
```

In case you have different requirements for trailing commas, you can modify `StringSplitOptions` and `string.Join` arguments (the current version arranged to your initial implementation).

This is definitely shorter and more idiomatic. But it is unlikely to be faster.

Comment: This is a nice one but it does not seem that Chunk is available? Gives the error of `CS1061 'List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Chunk' and no accessible extension method 'Chunk' accepting a first argument of type 'List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: It's available in the net6+ - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-6.0. You only need to add `using System.Linq;` to use it.

Answer (score 0):

All `Split` answers allocate at least 1 extra garbage object per number.

Here is no Linq version, faster than [@Etienne de Martel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77101047/5647513) version by using `IndexOf` and without extra allocation (`TrimEnd`)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

var str = "31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,0" +
          ",164,188,233,146,163,74,178,46,2,250" +
          ",123,159,167,168,187,174,109,8,9,10,";
var groupedBy10 = new List<string>();

int i = 0, li = 0, c = 0;
while (true)
{
    i = str.IndexOf(',', i + 1); // note: skips over first char
    if (i == -1)
    {
        var span = str.AsSpan(li, str.Length - li).TrimEnd(',');
        if (!span.IsEmpty) // omit empty group
            groupedBy10.Add(span.ToString());
        break;
    }
    if (++c == 10)
    {
        c = 0;
        groupedBy10.Add(str.Substring(li, i - li));
        li = i + 1; // skip coma
    }
}

foreach (var x in groupedBy10)
    Console.WriteLine($"'{x}'");
/* '31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,0'
   '164,188,233,146,163,74,178,46,2,250'
   '123,159,167,168,187,174,109,8,9,10' */
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's regex version. It matches anything plus a comma ten times and replaces it with match and new line at the end.

```
string pattern = @"(?:[^,]*,){10}";
string substitution = @"$&\n";
string input = @"31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,164,188,233,139,121,45,100,253,235,255,225,212,147,233,105,231,15";
        
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: You can add replacer function to add matches to list in one pass